# Optimize NumPy sum of matrices iterated through every element

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, cython

I'm working using **numpy 1.9**, **python 2.7** with opencv, dealing with big matrices and I have to make the following operation many times

```
def sumShifted(A):  # A: numpy array 1000*1000*10
    return A[:, 0:-1] + A[:, 1:]
```

I'd like to optimize this operation, if possible; I tried with [Cython](http://cython.org/) but I don't get any significant improvement but I do not exclude that it is because of my bad implementation.

Is there a way to make it faster?

**EDIT**:
`sumShifted` is getting called in a for loop like this:

```
for i in xrange(0, 400):
    # ... Various operations on B
    A = sumShifted(B)
    # ... Other operations on B


#More detailed
for i in xrange(0, 400):
    A = sumShifted(a11)
    B = sumShifted(a12)
    C = sumShifted(b12)
    D = sumShifted(b22)

    v = -upQ12/upQ11

    W, X, Z = self.function1( input_matrix, v, A, C[:,:,4], D[:,:,4] )
    S, D, F = self.function2( input_matrix, v, A, C[:,:,5], D[:,:,5] )
    AA      = self.function3( input_matrix, v, A, C[:,:,6], D[:,:,6] )
    BB      = self.function4( input_matrix, v, A, C[:,:,7], D[:,:,7] )
```

**EDIT2**: Following your advice I created this two runnable benchmarks (with Cython) about merging the 4 `sumShifted` methods in one.

```
A, B, C, D= improvedSumShifted(E, F, G, H)
#E,F: 1000x1000 matrices
#G,H: 1000x1000x8 matrices

#first implementation
def improvedSumShifted(np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=2] a, np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=2] b, np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=3] c, np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=3] d):
  cdef unsigned int i,j,k;
  cdef unsigned int w = a.shape[0], h = a.shape[1]-1, z = c.shape[2]
  cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=2] aa = np.empty((w, h))
  cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=2] bb = np.empty((w, h))
  cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=3] cc = np.empty((w, h, z))
  cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=3] dd = np.empty((w, h, z))
  with cython.boundscheck(False), cython.wraparound(False), cython.overflowcheck(False), cython.nonecheck(False):
    for i in range(w):
      for j in range(h):
        aa[i,j] = a[i,j] + a[i,j+1]
        bb[i,j] = b[i,j] + b[i,j+1]
        for k in range(z):
          cc[i,j,k] = c[i,j,k] + c[i,j+1,k]
          dd[i,j,k] = d[i,j,k] + d[i,j+1,k]
return aa, bb, cc, dd

#second implementation
def improvedSumShifted(np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=2] a, np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=2] b, np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=3] c, np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=3] d):
  cdef unsigned int i,j,k;
  cdef unsigned int w = a.shape[0], h = a.shape[1]-1, z = c.shape[2]
  cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=2] aa = np.copy(a[:, 0:h])
  cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=2] bb = np.copy(b[:, 0:h])
  cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=3] cc = np.copy(c[:, 0:h])
  cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=3] dd = np.copy(d[:, 0:h])
  with cython.boundscheck(False), cython.wraparound(False), cython.overflowcheck(False), cython.nonecheck(False):
  for i in range(w):
    for j in range(h):
      aa[i,j] += a[i,j+1]
      bb[i,j] += b[i,j+1]
      for k in range(z):
        cc[i,j,k] += c[i,j+1,k]
        dd[i,j,k] += d[i,j+1,k]

return aa, bb, cc, dd
```

Comment: Can you show us some code which explains how `sumShifted` is getting called?

Comment: @Rowandish [1000,1000,10] matrices are not big, although, **would you kindly also post your `.timeit()` measurements about what is your initial implementation speed, so as to benchmark anything to be better or not?**

Comment: @user3666197 my initial implementation speed is 6.827 seconds for 400 calls

Comment: I don't think there is a way to significantly improve `A[:, 0:-1] + A[:, 1:]`. Improving the `for-loop` *might* be possible. Can you post a minimal working example that we can benchmark and discuss?

Comment: Would be fair to state a few words on ***"Various operations on B[:,:,:]"*** as that decides about any feasible approach for a speed-up more than just the static sizes. If that computation strategy allows, there might be some ways how to introduce a viable faster process pipelining / segmentation / vectorisation / MapReduce. Thanks for your kind re-consideration.

Comment: @user3666197 I try to post a more detailed example. It is a bit difficult because of the complication of the code, I hope it is useful to understand the problem better

Comment: @unutbu I post a semplified and more detailed code

Comment: How is `i` being used? As it stands, it looks like the loop is computing the same thing 400 times... Please make the code runnable, so we have something concrete to benchmark.

Comment: @Rowandish Yes, that would mean a fair step forwards, as the acceleration potential of (possible) vectorised / other-accelerated approach x 400 loops accumulates

Comment: @unutbu I added a runnable benchmarks about the computationally longest part of my code

Comment: @Rowandish: I'm afraid there is a misunderstanding. Instead of trying to
optimize `sumShifted` you might try to optimize the `for-loop`. If you want help
doing that, we need to see in more detail what's going on in the whole
`for-loop`. There may be a way to improve it, or maybe not. But it is impossible
to say unless we can see the full code. You can substitute `function1` through
`function4` with dummy proxy functions if you know that is not the
bottlenecks. But we need to see more, because as it stands, you could improve
performance by simply removing the `for-loop` entirely.

Comment: @unutbu I get the point, you are right. Unfortunately it is not possible to post a runnable full code because it is very long and the functions I wrote are not bottlenecks. I understand that `sumShift` is not optimizable and so I'll try to change something else in my code. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is unlikely that this function can be sped up any further: It really does just four operations on python level:

1. (2x) Perform a slice on the input. These kinds of slices are very fast, as they only require a handful of integer operations to calculate new strides and sizes.
2. Allocate a new array for the output. For such a simple function, this is a significant burden.
3. Evaluate the `np.add` ufunc on the two slices, an operation that is highly optimised in numpy.

Indeed, my benchmarks show no improvement by either using numba or cython. On my machine, I consistently get ~30 ms per call if the output-array is pre-allocated, or ~50 ms if the memory allocation is taken into account.

The pure numpy versions:

```python
import numpy as np

def ss1(A):
    return np.add(A[:,:-1,:],A[:,1:,:])

def ss2(A,output):
    return np.add(A[:,:-1,:],A[:,1:,:],output)
```

The cython versions:

```python
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

def ss3(np.float64_t[:,:,::1] A not None):
    cdef unsigned int i,j,k;
    cdef np.float64_t[:,:,::1] ret = np.empty((A.shape[0],A.shape[1]-1,A.shape[2]),'f8')
    with cython.boundscheck(False), cython.wraparound(False):
        for i in range(A.shape[0]):
            for j in range(A.shape[1]-1):
                for k in range(A.shape[2]):
                    ret[i,j,k] = A[i,j,k] + A[i,j+1,k]
    return ret

def ss4(np.float64_t[:,:,::1] A not None, np.float64_t[:,:,::1] ret not None):
    cdef unsigned int i,j,k;
    assert ret.shape[0]>=A.shape[0] and ret.shape[1]>=A.shape[1]-1 and ret.shape[2]>=A.shape[2]
    with cython.boundscheck(False), cython.wraparound(False):
        for i in range(A.shape[0]):
            for j in range(A.shape[1]-1):
                for k in range(A.shape[2]):
                    ret[i,j,k] = A[i,j,k] + A[i,j+1,k]
    return ret
```

The numba version (current numba 0.14.0 cannot allocate new arrays in optimised functions):

```python
@numba.njit('f8[:,:,:](f8[:,:,:],f8[:,:,:])')
def ss5(A,output):
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(A.shape[1]-1):
            for k in range(A.shape[2]):
                output[i,j,k] = A[i,j,k] + A[i,j+1,k]
    return output
```

Here are the timings:

```python
>>> A = np.random.randn((1000,1000,10))
>>> output = np.empty((A.shape[0],A.shape[1]-1,A.shape[2]))

>>> %timeit ss1(A)
10 loops, best of 3: 50.2 ms per loop

>>> %timeit ss2(A,output)
10 loops, best of 3: 30.8 ms per loop

>>> %timeit ss3(A)
10 loops, best of 3: 50.8 ms per loop

>>> %timeit ss4(A,output)
10 loops, best of 3: 30.9 ms per loop

>>> %timeit ss5(A,output)
10 loops, best of 3: 31 ms per loop
```